# How to merge two parts?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

So i just started learning blender, and i have no idea how to merge/connect this two parts of my model. Can anybody pls help me?[image]

Comment: hello, are these 2 separate meshes or 2 separates objects? Have you tried the boolean operation or modifier?

Comment: Hello and welcome, if you are doing a sculpture, there is no need to join those, you should try to learn retopology

Comment: @moonboots Hi, these are two saparate meshes, in the same object.

Comment: You could use the boolean operation, or if you remesh in sculpt mode it will merge the different parts (R to set the face size, Ctrl R to apply)